# Django model class is None in manager

Tags: python, django, django-models, uwsgi

I'm getting a very weird error on my server running a django app. The error is not reproducable on my local development server.

I have this model and it's manager:

```
class CardManager(models.Manager):

    def get_by_identifier(self, card_identifier):
        ...
        for possible_suit in Card.SUITS:
            ...

class Card(models.Model):
    objects = CardManager()
    SUITS = ((1, 'Clubs'), ...)
```

This is the error:

```
AttributeError at /game/playcard/2/S1/

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SUITS'
```

and a traceback:

```
File "local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
    115. response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
    25. return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "views.py" in play_card
    155. card = Card.objects.get_by_identifier(card_identifier)
File "models.py" in get_by_identifier
    16. for possible_suit in Card.SUITS:
```

Running Django 1.5 (yea, I know), Python 2.7 and uwsgi

Any ideas? I'm leaning towards something uwsgi specific since I can't reproduce it on my local machine, but I wouldn't have any clue where to look...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`self.model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods) to access the model from the manager:

```
for possible_suit in self.model.SUITS:
    ...
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Is there a reason for this? Is it mentioned in the docs? I couldn't find anything earlier...